# Why are HTTP operations usually written in all caps?

Tags: history, http

I'm looking for the history of this. Why do we usually write HTTP `POST` or `OPTIONS` operations in all caps?

Comment: the practical answer is "because it doesn't work if you use lowercase".

Comment: @cas: Well, that just raises the question, "Why do HTTP servers not accept operations/tokens in a case-insensitive way?"

Comment: Which raises the obvious answer: "because they're not written to do that".  I said it was a **practical** answer, not an explanation of the underlying reason why - that's already adequately covered by both Thomas' and Anthon's answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is
 about the HTTP protocol and does not relate to Unix & Linux as defined in the [help].

Comment: @MichaelHomer I spent a good amount of time thinking which SE site would be appropriate for this question and ended up here. I with there was a tool or wiki page for directing you to the right site.

Answer (score 10):

[RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945) (1996) says

5.1.1 Method

The Method token indicates the method to be performed on the resource
identified by the Request-URI. The method is case-sensitive.

```
   Method         = "GET"                    ; Section 8.1
                  | "HEAD"                   ; Section 8.2
                  | "POST"                   ; Section 8.3
                  | extension-method
```

As for *why*, likely it was the influence of earlier protocols such as telnet ([RFC 854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854), 1983) which are old enough that uppercase was considered more portable  (and reliable) than ignoring case.

Some of RFC 1945 is case-insensitive, e.g.,

11. Access Authentication

HTTP provides a simple challenge-response authentication mechanism
which may be used by a server to challenge a client request and by a
client to provide authentication information. It uses an extensible,
case-insensitive token to identify the authentication scheme,
followed by a comma-separated list of attribute-value pairs which
carry the parameters necessary for achieving authentication via that
scheme.

and also the http URL itself:

The canonical form for "http" URLs is obtained by converting any
UPALPHA characters in host to their LOALPHA equivalent (hostnames are
case-insensitive), eliding the [ ":" port ] if the port is 80, and
replacing an empty abs_path with "/".

Answer (score 1):

This is probably just a result from the definition of those operations in the RFC using all caps. For other (older) protocols, even if the actual implementation might not be case sensitive, the operations' description in RFC is in all caps as well.

It might be because that makes them stand out in the text only documents in which there is no other way to emphasis specific terms (like using **bold** or *italics*).